# Capture Option vs useCapture

Tags: javascript

The docs for `addEventListener/removeEventListener` both have a `capture` option and a `useCapture` parameter.

On its face these seem to do the exact same thing. Could someone elaborate if there are any differences or preferred? Should I use both if I want event listeners added/removed in the capture phase?

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same, [here](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener) you can find details.

> For historical reasons, options can also be false/true, that’s the same as {capture: false/true}.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31662431)